# Slide show/hide content on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to find a solution to what I want to do but nothing matches exactly. Closest thing I have found is a tab accordion. To be precise, I have a horizontal menu comprised of links that when clicked will show extra content below the row of links with a nice slide down animation, and slide up when the same link is clicked (the rest of the page content moves when the hidden content is revealed, which is what I want).

The problem is that when other links are clicked they also show extra content but the content from an earlier click is still visible. I want that earlier content to slide up before the new content slides down. Is this possible, and if it is, how do I go about accomplishing it?

Here's the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hides the menu as soon as the DOM is ready
    $('#about').hide();
    $('#search').hide();
    $('#pages').hide();
    $('#links').hide();
    // toggles the menu on clicking the noted link  
    $('#toggleabout').click(function() {
        $('#about').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });

    $('#togglesearch').click(function() {
        $('#search').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });

    $('#togglepages').click(function() {
        $('#pages').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });

    $('#togglelinks').click(function() {
        $('#links').slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a simple call to

```
$(".your-element-class").slideUp();
```

to close all elements before calling slideDown on the next one. If however you are having more troubles, please post some code and/or improve your description of the problem you are encountering specifically.

Comment: I have posted the code I am currently using. I attempted your method however it seems that it will only slideUp on already hidden content, it ignores the call to slideDown. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Ignore what I said earlier, what happens is that it gets stuck in a slideUp/slideDown 'loop', not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: @Sovereign Anarchei, Take a look at this jsfiddle based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcx88/. I added a class to each element that can be hidden and just hid (slid) them all when I clicked on another item, then I called slideToggle() (really, you could just call slideDown at that point instead)

Comment: @SovereignAnarchei: I just made a small amendment to allow the content to be hidden again after the user clicks on the same button twice: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcx88/1/. Notice the "not" pseudo-selector.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this really helped. I also used `.delay(500)` before the `.slideToggle(400)` to smooth out the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your other slideable links inside an array. Now when a user clicks a link, check your array to make sure that the other links are collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like, I don't know how you identify your submenu's but I just pick the id of the A and put a `-navcontent` after the ID of the submenu:

```
$("#mynav li a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent jumping to top of page
    $("[id$='-navcontent']").slideUp(); // Slide up all other -navcontent elements
    $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "-navcontent").slideToggle(); // Slidedown the current -navcontent element
});
```

More information about the `$=` can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// hides the menu as soon as the DOM is ready
$('#about, #search, #pages, #links').hide();

// toggles the menu on clicking the noted link  
    $("#mynav input:button").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent jumping to top of page
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("toggle", "");

    $("#mynav input:button").each(function(){ // Slide up all elements which are visible
        var innerID = $(this).attr("id").replace("toggle", "");
        if(id == innerID) return; // Prevent current item to slideUp and slideDown directly after eachother, if is currentItem, only hide.
        $("#" + innerID).slideUp();
    });
    $("#" + id).slideToggle(); // Slidedown the current -navcontent element
});

});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcx88/2/

Comment: I have posted the code I am currently using. I attempted your method, and while appreciate how it should work in theory, in practice nothing happened when I clicked the links. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The way I made the function is the other way around as you got it. You got a link with `toggle` in front of the name, where I add a part to the ID of the DIV that is toggled. I updated my code. You have to change the `#mynav li a` to whatever structure you are using.

Comment: I tried a different way and got the effect I was after, thanks for helping though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Good luck! But the code I wrote can be used for any number of tabs. And you don't need to generate any more code if a tab changes ID or gets removed / added.